# SOAP Webservice with Java - Framework?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

which is the best framework for implementing and defining a SOAP web service with Java? Is it `JAX WS`?

Basically, I want to send a business report (based on XML) from the client to the server. The server validates this report and sends back a status report that the client can evaluate.

I think that SOAP is the way to go since it's an established standard in computer to computer communication.

Thanks for suggestions!

Marco

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to start from Java Code, JAX-WS is the established standard (possible enhanced through [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) or [Axis 2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/))

If you want to start with XML, use [Spring Web Services](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/)

(see [why contract first](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/why-contract-first.html) for the discussion of the difference)